# WhatsApp API Link are not Functioning on Desktop Anymore

Tags: whatsapp

So if you have not chatted with a number in the past and try to chat with the number using the Whatsapp API URL: https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=XXXXXXXXXXXX
it gives the error "Phone Number shared via url is invalid."

Due to this have noticed all chat sender bots have stopped working on desktop.

Normally the API Link used to work perfectly fine on Desktop, but for the past 4 days it has stopped working for numbers which you have not chatted with in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

To add a message

```
https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=xxxxxxxxxxxx&text=Hi!
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct format

```
 https://wa.me/1XXXXXXXXX
```

Where `1` is the country code

Checkout Whatsapp documentation [documentation](https://faq.whatsapp.com/5913398998672934/?helpref=hc_fnav)